# How to make nginx only respond to one domain?

Tags: nginx, domain

I am pretty new to nginx, I host my rails application on nginx+passenger. I want my website to be accessible to only one domain. So I set my nginx conf like the following:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  mydomain.com www.mydomain.com;
    root /var/deploy/myapp/current/public;
    passenger_enabled on;

    location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$ {
        expires 1y;
        add_header    Cache-Control  public;
    }
 }
```

I specify the `server_name` directive, but still, it answers anything which points to this IP and I could see that in the access.log that it answers to other domain names.

Is there anything I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Either make a new virtualhost in addition to the current one in nginx that catches all other domains except the one domain for rails. Or you need to get a dedicated IP-address for your domain.

Comment: Thanks pkhamre. I have a dedicated ip-address for my domain. The thing is, some other domain name is also pointing to my application(there's some story I also don't know). So you mean I need to create a another block with `server_name _;` and returns 404 error always?

Comment: Yes, a server-block with "server_name _;" will do the trick.

Comment: worked like a charm!

Comment: Great! I'm glad I could help :)